# Есть ли функция(встроенная в php)вычисляющая  сумму двойнного массива?

Tags: php

```
 $_SESSION[idt][id7];                    
   $_SESSION[idt][id4];
   $_SESSION[idt][id9];    
   функция?($_SESSION[idt]);
```

Comment: я, конечно, не специалист в этом чудесном языке, но, думаю, ее там нет, также, как и, например, такой полезной функции, что возвращает второй с конца символ в отчестве Саддама Хусейна

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нет

Comment: +1: Самый короткий из правильных ответов :)

Answer (score 1):

Судя по вашему коду, вам нужна не сумма двойного массива, а лишь сумма обыкновенного массива: исходя из вопроса, `$_SESSION[idt]` -- это "одинарный" массив!

Для обыкновенного массива подойдёт [`array_sum`](http://ideone.com/TWRQKM).

Comment: у него ассоц. массив.

Comment: @Maris: `array_sum` работает с ассоциативными массивами: http://ideone.com/8c1V63